# Application Pool Start/Stop/Recycle "This method is not implemented in any class" Error

Tags: c#, windows, iis, wmi, application-pool

I am having issues starting/stopping/recycling my application pool that is located on a remote server. I have coded a function that will tell me what application pools are on a server (along with their status). However, I get the error "**System.Management.ManagementException: This method is not implemented in any class**" whenever I run the following snippet of code.

```
// getScope creates a ManagementScope object
ManagementScope scope = getScope(serverName, "microsoftiisv2", username, password);
scope.Connect();

ObjectQuery objectquery = new ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM IISApplicationPoolSetting");
ManagementObjectSearcher mos = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, objectquery);
ManagementObjectCollection moc = mos.Get();

foreach (ManagementObject mo in moc)
{
    string path = mo["Name"].ToString();
    string name = path.Split('/')[2];
    string pstate = mo["AppPoolState"].ToString();

    if (name == applicationPoolName && pstate == "2")
    {
        string[] parameters = { "" };
        mo.InvokeMethod("Stop", null);
        // I have also tried the following alternatives:
        // mo.InvokeMethod( "Stop", parameters )
    }
}
```

I have tried looking at the Windows documentation, but have had no success understanding why my code does not work.

Comment: Please use `Microsoft.Web.Administration` API or the PowerShell cmdlets. WMI and ADSI API are considered obsolete.

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation, Lex. I will look into them.